# Xcode 6 and Cocoapods using versions 0.34.4 & cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods

I have a problem with cocoapods using versions 0.34.4 & cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2 
After I updated my laptop to OS X Yosemite I had to update gems and cocoapods and my old iOS project stop working

I'm getting the following errors:

```
using cocoapods-0.34.4:
ld: library not found for -lPods-Evernote-SDK-iOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

using cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2:
There is a circular dependency between ShareKit/NoARC and ShareKit/Core
```

Here is my podfile contents, Any Help ??

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


pod 'CXAlertView'
pod 'ShareKit'
pod 'JSONKit'
pod 'FPPopover'
pod 'Base64'
pod 'CZDateFormatterCache'
pod 'JMImageCache'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'MFSideMenu'
pod 'ASIHTTPRequest'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your current 0.35.0 version you could just run:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

you must install a specific version of cocoa pods via the command:

`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.34.4`

than `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating new project! 
I used cocoapods-0.34.4 with the new project

Comment: Hmmm. That's quite radical! Did you find out what was wrong before?